# iOS Push Notification Certificate Private Key not being accepted by server

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl-certificate

I'm currently trying to enable my server for Push Notifications and I'm at the stage where I need to upload the SSL certificates. I followed the steps in a Ray Wenderlich P.N. tutorial, but I can't get my server to accept the private key file. Tutorial can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

So I create the certificate (I'm doing a distribution one by the way, not development as in the tutorial) and convert it to a `.pem`. The server accepts this fine. I then export a non-password protected `.p12` file from KeyChain Access. I do it without a password because the server requires that the Private Key is **not** password protected. At first I tried uploading this `.p12` and it gave an error saying it could not parse the private key. I then decided to convert the `.p12` to a non-password protected `.pem`. When I upload this to the server, I get a "key.pem is empty...." error. I'm not entirely sure where to go from here to be honest. The server I'm with is called appfog.com.

If anyone could help with the uploading of this private key for use on the server, I'd appreciate it.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: "I do it without a password because the server requires that the Private Key is not password protected" I don't believe! :) -it is to bad for you. BTW: if are you using your mac mini to as server it will not work, until you aren't buying the Server version of OS or a package, Take care of the OS too

Comment: Yea, I thought that too, but there doesn't seem to be another way of doing it without leaving it unprotected.

Comment: for sure it is, for me took me 5 days to configure properly thr first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it through another means. My backend developer ended up utilising those very certificates and everything is working nicely now.

Regards,
Mike